# Minimal resolutions of singularities in higher dimensions and their cobordism class.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, singularity-theory

For a given singular algebraic variety over $\mathbb{C}$, how many minimal resolutions can exist? More specifically, consider a projective quadratic cone $Q$ in $\mathbb{C}P^{4}$ (with homogeneous coordinates $x_{i},\ i=0,\ 1,\,...,\ 4$), given by single equation: $x_{0}x_{3}-x_{1}x_{2} = 0.$ The only singular point of $Q$ has coordinates $[0:0:0:0:1].$ Is there any way to study minimal resolutions of this cone? Especially I am interested in the relation of Thom's complex cobordism class of minimal resolution and the ambient one in this case.

Comment: This is a very interesting question that requires a much lengthier answer than I can write at the moment. For a discussion of your specific example, search for the keywords _Atiyah flop_. In particular you could read the relevant parts of the article _Twenty-five years of threefolds --- an old person's view_ by Miles Reid.